# Why does the compiler ignore the difference between pointer and constant pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Messing with some legacy C libraries which use raw pointers I found this to be interesting:

```
// test.hpp

namespace test
{
    void foo(int const* arg);
}
```

```
// test.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

void test::foo(int* arg)
{
    // implementation...
}
```

Obviously, this won't compile, because `void foo(int*)` was not declared anywhere in namespace `test`.

But what about this?

```
// test.hpp

namespace test
{
    void foo(int* const arg);
}
```

```
// test.cpp

#include "test.hpp"

void test::foo(int* arg)
{
    arg = nullptr;
}
```

This successfully compiles with GCC 12.1.0.

But why is that? In the declaration of `foo()` in `test.hpp` we say that `arg` is a constant pointer which can not be modified. Thus, `void foo(int* const)` and `void foo(int*)` should technically be the prototypes of two different functions. Why does the compiler consider them to be the same?

Note, this is not a question about the difference between constant pointer and pointer to a constant. The question is about the logic of the compiler - why does it consider two functions to be the same when they are technically not?

Comment: Reminder, there are 4 types of pointers:  1) mutable pointer to mutable data; 2) constant pointer to mutable data; 3) constant pointer to constant data; and 4) mutable pointer to constant data.  When a *pointer* is constant, the pointer can't be modified.  A pointer an point to constant data (read only) or it can point to mutable data (read / write).

Comment: Forget about pointers here, it's a red herring. Consider `void f(int x);` and `void f(const int x);`. From the _caller_ point of view, they will take the exact same arguments. Sure, in the actual implementations, only one of these can modify the local copy `x`, but that's invisible to the caller. Since they are equivalent for the caller, they offer the same "interface", hence C++ will ignore the "const-ness" in the prototype when it directly refers to the argument (but not in the other cases, as in `void f(const T &x); void f(const T *x); etc.`).